# Working with bits in PHP

Tags: php, binary

Say I want to store a sequence of 8 words in PHP, and I don't want to use compression.

Since there are only 8 words, I could assign each one a binary value and then store these binary values in a file instead of the ascii words.

The possible binary values would be:

```
000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111
```

This would be much more efficient to parse because: (1) each word is now the same size, and, (2) it takes up much less space.

My question is:

How can I do this in PHP? How can I assign a binary value to something, then write this to a file (writing the bits how I want them), then read this back again?

The reason I want to do this is to create an efficient indexing system.

Comment: I suppose this is just a simplified example for a bigger data set, isn't it?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, yes the full dataset is about 1TB.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8874693/1920232

Comment: do u want to use default binary as provided by PHP or your own

Comment: give me some sleep and I will anwser your question with an example. but having still a little bug ;)

Comment: I've managed to create the 3bit encoding function. But you can just encode 7 different words with it. You need 1 extra sequence that marks the end of data when there is a gap between data bits and the last full byte (likely)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*First*, if you want to compress data, use php builtin functions for that like the gzip extension..

But as you requested, I've prepared an example how this can be done in PHP. It is not perfect, just a trivial implementation. The compression rate could be better if I would use the gap between bit 30 and 32 of each integer. Maybe will add this feature... However I've used 32bit unsigned integers in favour of bytes as with them the loss is 2 bits per 32 bits instead of 2 bits per byte.

First we prepare the lookup table that contains the relations word => decimal number, its the coding table:

```
<?php

// coding table
$lookupTable = array (
//  'word0' => chr(0), // reserved for 0 byte gap in last byte
    'word1' => chr(1),
    'word2' => chr(2),
    'word3' => chr(3),
    'word4' => chr(4),
    'word5' => chr(5),
    'word6' => chr(6),
    // reserve one word for white space
    ' ' => chr(7)
);
```

Then comes the compression function:

```
/**
 *
 */
function _3bit_compress($text, $lookupTable) {

    echo 'before compression                  : ' . strlen($text) . ' chars', PHP_EOL;

    // first step is one byte compression using the lookup table
    $text = strtr($text, $lookupTable);
    echo 'after one byte per word compression : ' . strlen($text) . ' chars', PHP_EOL;

    $bin = ''; // the result
    $carrier = 0; // 32 bit usingned int can 'carry' 10 words in 3 bit notation

    for($c = 0; $c < strlen($text); $c++) {
        $triplet = $c % 10;
        // every 30 bits we add the 4byte unsigned integer to $bin.
        // please read the manual of pack
        if($triplet === 0 && $carrier !== 0) {
            $bin .= pack('N', $carrier);
            $carrier = 0;
        }

        $char = $text[$c];
        $carrier  <<= 3; // make space for the the next 3 bits
        $carrier += ord($char); // add the next 3 bit pattern
        // echo $carrier, ' added ' . ord($char), PHP_EOL;
    }
    $bin .= pack('N', $carrier); // don't forget the remaining bits
    echo 'after 3 bit compression             : ' . strlen($bin) . ' chars', PHP_EOL;
    return $bin;
}
```

And the decompression function:

```
/**
 *
 */
function _3_bit_uncompress($compressed, $lookupTable) {
    $len = strlen($compressed);
    echo 'compressed length:            : ' . $len . ' chars', PHP_EOL;

    $i = 0;
    $tmp = '';
    $text = '';
    // unpack string as 4byte unsigned integer
    foreach(unpack('N*', $compressed) as $carrier) {
        while($i < 10) {
            $code = $carrier & 7; // get the next code
            // echo $carrier . ' ' . $code, PHP_EOL;
            $tmp = chr($code) . $tmp;
            $i++;
            $carrier >>= 3; // shift forward to the next 3 bits
        }
        $i = 0;
        $text = $text . $tmp;
        $tmp = '';
    }
    // reverse translate from decimal codes to words
    return strtr($text, array_flip($lookupTable));
}
```

Now its time to test the functions :)

```
$original = <<<EOF
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word1 word3 word3  word2
EOF;


$compressed = _3bit_compress($original, $lookupTable);
$restored = _3_bit_uncompress($compressed, $lookupTable);

echo 'compressed size: ' . round(strlen($compressed) * 100 / strlen($original), 2) . '%', PHP_EOL;

echo 'Message before compression  : ' . $original, PHP_EOL;
echo 'Message after decompression : ' . $restored, PHP_EOL;
```

The example should give you:

```
before compression                  : 60 chars
after one byte per word compression : 20 chars
after 3 bit compression             : 8 chars
compressed length:            : 8 chars
compressed size: 13,33%
Message before compression  : word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word1 word3 word3  word2
Message after decompression : word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word1 word3 word3  word2
```

If we are testing with loooong words the compression rate will of course get even better:

```
before compression                  : 112 chars
after one byte per word compression : 16 chars
after 3 bit compression             : 8 chars
compressed length:            : 8 chars
compressed size: 7,14%
Message before compression  : wooooooooord1 wooooooooord2 wooooooooord2 wooooooooord3 wooooooooord1 wooooooooord2 wooooooooord2 wooooooooord3 
Message after decompression : wooooooooord1 wooooooooord2 wooooooooord2 wooooooooord3 wooooooooord1 wooooooooord2 wooooooooord2 wooooooooord3
```

Comment: Note that this is just a fictional example. It will not work with real world data. It's just to show how to work with bits in PHP. Real World compression algorithms would mostly analyze the entropy in a string and create the coding table dynamically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your functions, this shows me how it works. FYI the purpose of this is not to compress the data, but to make it very fast to look up say the 32405th word in a file, since the word sizes will all be the same I can just grab those bits out of the file without having to parse the whole thing or count spaces.

Comment: @Alasdair You are welcome. It was really a fun to answer this. And I like to work with bits in times where the regular answer might be: 'Use XML, JSON, ...' <- ironic :) I'm not sure if the word lookup task can be done faster using bits. Although the search input data will be smaller, the effort to search for a word might be more or less the same. I would like if you can drop a comment on this if you have results. I would use something like a heap structure for those fast lookups... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29

Comment: The point is that everything is the same length, so if I want the 10,000th word then I can just seek to 3bits * 10,000 and there it is! Very much faster than iterating through spaces.